# pyspark using sql queries and doing group by optimisation

Tags: sql, pyspark

In spark one can write sql queries as well use spark api functions. ReduceByKey should always be used than groupbykey as it prevents more shuffling.

I would like to know, when you use sql queries by registering the dataframe how can we use reduceby ? In sql queries there is only group by no reduce by. Do internally it optimises to use reduceBykey than a group by ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I actually did an explain to understand the physical plan and it first executes a function as `partial_sum` and then after that executes the function `sum` which implies that it has first performed a sum within executors and then shuffled across.